# The plane described by the equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is invariant under the affine map $f$ if and only if $(a,b,c,d)$ is an eigenvector of $M$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, plane-geometry, affine-geometry, invariant-subspace

My lecture notes include the following result with no proof:

**Theorem:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be an affine map with corresponding linear function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, that is, for any vector $w\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and point $p\in \mathbb{R}^3$ (the affine space we are dealing with has $\mathbb{R}^3$ as both its set of point and as its vector space) we have that $$f(p+v)=f(p)+\phi(v).$$ Then the plane $P$ described by the equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is invariant under $f$ if and only if the vector $$u=(a,b,c,d)^T$$ is an eigenvector of $M^T$, where $M$ is the [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix) of $f$.

---

I've tried playing with the identities $$v\in P \Leftrightarrow u\cdot \begin{pmatrix} v \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = u\cdot \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =0$$

as well as

$$v'\in P \Leftrightarrow u\cdot \begin{pmatrix} v' \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = u\cdot \begin{pmatrix} x'\\ y' \\ z' \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =u\cdot (Mv)=0$$

where $v'=f(v)=(x',y',z')$ and $M$ is the [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix) of $f$. Although I have not been able to prove either direction.

---

How could one prove the result?

Comment: Hint: The plane (which passes through the origin) is perpendicular to what vector ? How can we show that this vector is invariant, and from there conclude that the plane is invariant?

Comment: @CalvinLin the plane is perpendicular to $u=(a,b,c,d)^T$. Beyond that I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Right, the plan is perpendicular to $u$. For the plane to be invariant, the normal has to be invariant. How does that relate to the normal vector being an eigenvector of $ \phi$?

Comment: You should edit to say that $f$ is an *affine* function with corresponding linear function $\phi$.

Comment: @CalvinLin do you mean to say that $P$ is invariant under $f$ if and only if $\langle u \rangle$ is invariant under $f$? If so, I do not know how to prove it. The latter condition is of course equivalent to $u$ being an eigenvector of $\phi$.

Comment: Be explicit about the definition of an affine map and the relation to the linear map $\phi\colon\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use $v$ to stand for $(x,y,z,1)^T$. Then use $u\cdot v=u^T v$, and your derivations are almost there.

$u^T M v =0=v^T M^T u$ and $u^T v=0 = v^T u$ for all $v$ of the form $(x,y,z,1)^T$ implies
$$M^T u = \lambda u.$$